# How to properly add dependecy of entity class to other classes and reduce coupling

Tags: c#, design-patterns, coupling, dependency-inversion

I was reading the dependency inversion principle. It states that the module should be dependent on abstraction. I understand most of the parts, and I can apply them. There is one place where there is confusion.

Whenever we call a dependent class method. We sometimes pass parameter as an object. And this object needs to be instantiated and pass as parameter

**Entity.cs**

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

**ClientClass.cs**

```
public class ClientClass
{
    private readonly IDependentClass _dep;
    public ClientClass(IDependentClass dep)
    {
         _dep = dep;
    }
    public void Method()
    {
         var e = new Entity();
         _dep.Method(e)
    }
}
```

**DependentClass.cs**

```
public class DependentClass: IDependentClass
{
    public void Method(Entity e)
    {
    }
}
```

Here the Entity class is just a data transfer object. But it has a concrete dependency on ClientClass and DependentClass which violates the DIP.
Is my understanding correct? How to fix this?

Comment: You'll probably need to either have a factory class/method or follow explicit dependency principle and pass the entity as a parameter to the method explicitly, moving the responsibility of initializing the entity to the caller of the function. This now asks the question if client is needed and whether the caller of client should just be dependent on `IDependentClass` explicitly instead of a pass  through client. **(based on your example)**

Comment: Wait. if Entity is just a dto and has no functionality or dependencies then there is no tight coupling in creating an instance to be used in a function.

Answer (score 1):

you can create interface IEntity too to follow DI principles

```
public interface IEntity
{
     string Prop1 {get; set;}
    string Prop2 {get; set;}
}

public class DependentClass: IDependentClass
{
    public void Method(IEntity e)
    {
    }
}
```

but as @Nicosi noticed in this case you will not gain much with IEntity interface. I makes sense only if you have any methods too and you can use polymorphism and Liskov substitution Principle (LSP) with DI together.

I don't see much sense using

```
 var e = new Entity();
```

inside of Method() since you create an empty object and breaking DI too

Try this

```
public class ClientClass
{
    private readonly IDependentClass _dep;
    public ClientClass(IDependentClass dep)
    {
         _dep = dep;
    }
    public void Method(IEntity e)
    {
      
         _dep.Method(e)
    }
}
```

another way to use DI  could be

```
public class ClientClass
{
    private readonly IDependentClass _dep;
    private readonly IEntity _ent;

    public ClientClass(IDependentClass dep, IEntity ent)
    {
         _dep = dep;
        _ent=ent;
    }
    public void Method()
    {
      
         _dep.Method(_ent);
    }
}
```

But it looks funny for me

Comment: Does entity really need to be abstracted if it has no functionality other than being a DTO? I am interested in your thoughts/views about that.

Comment: I agree with passing it into client explicitly via method

Comment: @Nkosi You are right, in this case we don't gain anything, but I was not sure if PO showed the whole class,  maybe  entity has some methods too

Comment: Agreed but they stated at the end that Entity is just a DTO. I guess we'll just have to wait till OP clarifies that.

Comment: Entity is a DTO with no method in it. We use it to pass it as a parameter to the function. Why are we not considering Entity as a dependency? I have a take along the entity class whenever I want to use the Dependent class

Comment: @nak Di is this line of code public ClientClass(IDependentClass dep, IEntity ent). You can replace it with public ClientClass(IDependentClass dep, Entity ent). It is still DI since you don't create a concrete class inside of another class.

Comment: But  Liskov Substitution Principle will not be followed This is why SOLID principles expect using interfaces.